# How to read CDATA in XML file with PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, cdata

I am having a difficult time reading an XML file with Cdata inside.

## in $xmlsource

```
<list>
  <topic>
     <topicTitle>Test</topicTitle>
     <topicDetail><![CDATA[<br>randomHTMLhere</br>]]></topicDetail>
  </topic>
</list>
```

## powershell

```
[xml]$xml = get-content $xmlsource    

foreach ($topic in $xml.list) {
    $topic.topicTitle
    $topic.topicDetail
}
```

$topic.topicDetail will be null while $topic.topicTitle will not be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`$topic.topicDetail."#cdata-section"`

or

`$topic.topicDetail.InnerText`

Comment: Thanks! I then used
.get_FirstChild().get_Data() to access it.

Comment: Nice. Note that you ca also *set* CDATA like that: `$topic.topicDetail."#cdata-section" = "foo" ... $xml.Save($path)`